# How to tell LaTeX to automatically remove envelopping curly braces in a string to use with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, urls, braces

I am using biblatex together with a bibliography manager Referencer. I want to use the url field of the bib file to link to the page. However, Referencer has urls of the form

```
url = {{ http://... }}
```

rather than the usual format with only a single brace. Url fields are interpreted literally in biblatex and so I get links to `{ http:// ... }` in the pdf and they consequently do not work. Since every time I change the bibliography file through Referencer the curly braces reappear, going through the bib file and removing the extra braces is not a solution for me. Is there a way to tell LaTeX to automatically remove the braces before passing the result to `\href`?

Comment: Why is Referencer doing this: it's wrong.

Comment: I think it's because URL is a custom field in Referencer and it adds double braces to all of the custom fields if you want it to add double braces to other fields (such as title), where they are desirable. You can set this via the option "Protect capitalization". But if I switch this off I won't get double braces anywhere.

Comment: Taking a look at how Referencer works, it seems that when you select 'Protect capitalization' it adds braces around the entire content of almost _every_ field. I would say that this is not a good idea: braces should be used only where needed. I would suggest using a BibTeX-focussed manager, such as JabRef.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is a bad idea. Is there no way to do string processing in LaTeX and remove the braces that way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you are using biblatex 2.0+ and biber 1.0+ and put this in your preamble:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=url,
            match=\regexp{\A\{(.+)\}\z},
            replace=$1]
    }
  }
}
```

Of course the regexp can be tuned to your liking. See section 4.5.2 of the current `biblatex` manual.