# Regex replacement for biblatex/biber to eliminate the warning "month not integer..."

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, natbib, biber, sorting

I am using `biblatex` with `biber` from TL2018 for my PhD thesis. Due to various reasons, I am forced to use `Mendeley` for citation managements and cannot switch to another tool now. Mendeley is capable of generating a `bib` file - but it is compatible with **only** the classic `natbib/bibtex` combo (although it correctly escapes special characters).

I understand that with `biblatex/biber` combo, the `month` field is not a string, but rather must be an integer.  So, as expected and discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330179/month-field-not-an-integer-will-not-sort-properly), I get the warning

```
 [784] Utils.pm:193> WARN - month field 'Apr' in entry 'coolauthor2012' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
```

Taking inspiration from a tangentially related question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67780/how-to-tell-latex-to-automatically-remove-envelopping-curly-braces-in-a-string-t?rq=1), I used the following `month -> integer` hand-conversion in the preamble.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map[overwrite]{
            \step[fieldsource=month, match={jan}, replace=${1}]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match={feb}, replace=${2}]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match={mar}, replace=${3}]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match={apr}, replace=${4}]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match={may}, replace=${5}]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match={jun}, replace=${6}]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match={jul}, replace=${7}]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match={aug}, replace=${8}]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match={sep}, replace=${9}]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match={oct}, replace=${10}]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match={nov}, replace=${11}]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match={dec}, replace=${12}]
        }
    }
}
```

I have two nagging questions now.

1. Will this work? I don't see any more of the aforementioned warnings, but I wonder if the citations are correctly sorted, and the month replacement was indeed accounted for and handled correctly.
2. Is there a better way to handle this problem? Clearly, hand-mapping each month to an integer is not efficient.

This will help all folks who want to use `mendeley` especially for re-using their existing `mendeley` library for manuscript submissions to publishers who are mostly stuck behind in `natbib/bibtex` era.

Comment: Note that `month = {apr},` is also wrong for most classical BibTeX styles, they just won't complain as loudly as Biber.

Comment: @moewe what should it be instead? I only looked at couple of examples , 'jan' and 'feb' and proceeded with the conversion assuming that the month fields generated by ```mendeley``` shall always be three-character abbreviations. Am I wrong? Is ```apr``` the only exception?

Comment: The three-letter abbreviations are valid but should be written **without** braces. So `month = apr,` would be correct. Naturally `apr` is not special and all months behave the same.

Comment: Ha. Got it.... I think I wasn't clear in the question. ```mendeley``` does indeed generate the month-fields in all entries in the exported ```bib``` file  as ```{jan}, {feb}, {mar}``` and so on (with the braces).  Also, I have no clue of using regexes. Does it mean that my replacement string is wrong? Should it be ```, replace=1```, I also wonder that that ```$``` is doing there. I'd appreciate some help in correctly formulating this ```month -> integer``` conversion command.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was not clear. I was just saying that Mendeley is wrong to produce these strings with braces *even for BibTeX*. (This is contradicting your claim that this is (only) compatible with `natbib`/BibTeX - it usually isn't.)

Comment: hmm... But ```mendeley``` is far too popular, particularly in the UK, right? I wonder why would they make such an elementary mistake? And, naturally one expects that such an error should have been noticed by someone else long time time". I am using the latest ```mendeley``` version 1.19.1. They claim ```bibtex``` compatibility in their manuals/software interface. Is there a credible source/reference link that you could point me to that supports your claim that ```month``` abbreviations should not be surrounded by braces?

Comment: http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf says: "You should use the standard three-letter abbreviation, as described in Appendix B.1.3 of the LaTeX book." which indeed does not specifically address whether or not the field value should be delimited. Item 9 on p. 13 uses undelimited months, which could give a hint towards best practice. I don't have the LaTeX book at hand to check what it has to say, but I can refer you to Q13 of http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxFAQ.pdf

Comment: @moewe amazing. Thanks for pointing to the reference. I wonder why ```mendeley``` cripples its users this way.

Comment: I assume they are just oblivious of the shortcomings of their current approach. Not many people need the `month` field and maybe some people don't care. Plus I'm not sure how large the LaTeX user base of Mendeley is. There are some long-standing issues with Mendeleys `.bib` export that have not been fixed (I think I once saw quite an old thread on a Mendeley feedback site about URLs and escaped characters, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436684/c/436687#comment1095539_436684). (Re the `month`s again: https://www.ece.ucdavis.edu/~jowens/biberrors.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\A(j|J)an(uary)?\Z}, replace=1]
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\A(f|F)eb(ruary)?\Z}, replace=2]
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\A(m|M)ar(ch)?\Z}, replace=3]
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\A(a|A)pr(il)?\Z}, replace=4]
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\A(m|M)ay\Z}, replace=5]
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\A(j|J)un(e)?\Z}, replace=6]
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\A(j|J)ul(y)?\Z}, replace=7]
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\A(a|A)ug(ust)?\Z}, replace=8]
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\A(s|S)ep(tember)?\Z}, replace=9]
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\A(o|O)ct(ober)?\Z}, replace=10]
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\A(n|N)ov(ember)?\Z}, replace=11]
      \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\A(d|D)ec(ember)?\Z}, replace=12]
    }
  }
}
```

This replaces either three-letter name abbreviations or full month names with the correct month number. Since Biber's RegExp is case sensitive this matches the lower-case month abbreviation and the version where the first letter is capitalised (i.e. `jan` and `Jan`). (`biber` 2.12 and higher support `matchi` for case-insensitive matches; see [this issue](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/235).)

This is only needed to suppress the warnings that Biber throws when it is presented with

```
month = {mar},
```

even without this code the month will be correctly recognised.

---

Note that for most BibTeX styles `month = {mar},` is also not the best (correct) form of input. The brace-less `month = mar,` is usually better because it is then converted to the desired output via BibTeX strings. Q13 of [BibTeX Tips and FAQ](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxFAQ.pdf)

> **Q13: Should I use words or numerals for the month, edition, etc., fields, and why?**
>
> You should always use the three letter month macros (undelimited) for the name of the month (`jan`, `feb`, `mar`, `apr`, `may`, `jun`, `jul`, `aug`, `sep`, `oct`, `nov`, `dec`) as this lets each `.bst` file format the month names as is
>   required for that bibliography style.

[BTXdoc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) states on p. 10

> **`month`** The  month  in  which  the  work  was  published or,  for an unpublished work, in which it was written.  You should use the standard three-letter abbreviation, as described in Appendix B.1.3 of the LaTeX book

See also https://www.ece.ucdavis.edu/~jowens/biberrors.html

Comment: This does not work. I get an error ```! Undefined control sequence.
\blx@tempf ...e="month" map\string _match="\regex
                                                  {\Ajan \Z }" map_replace="1"```

Comment: @Krishna I forgot a `p` try again, please

Comment: Yay. Yes, got the regex```p``` fixed. That did work!  I wonder why ```mendeley``` folks haven't noticed that even their basic ```bibtex``` export is broken with the braces and stuff. But thank you for your help. Upvoted and marked as accepted.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286261/35864

Comment: This stopped working with a recent update of `biblatex/biber`. Sigh! I don't know why. Is this still working for you.

Comment: @Krishna There has not been an update for `biblatex` or Biber since February and the answer was posted in June so it was tested with the current version. I just tested in a short example and it still works for me (i.e. it suppresses the Biber warning one would get from `month = {mar},`). If it does not work for you, please ask a new question with an MWE and with the `.blg` file.

Comment: upon close inspection, the warning is due to lowercase month-names. How can the regex be widened to catch this one? I think it is preferable to update this question so that other Mendeley users facing this may have a single reference page . I asked the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450116/regex-replacement-with-lowercase-monthnames-for-biblatex-biber-to-eliminate-the), but this is looks strongly like a duplicate to me.